# How can I remove 0 & negative values(-1 to -100) in weight module section?

Tags: 7

I want to remove 0 and negative values (-1 to -100),so need to display only 1 to 100 items only  in drop down list .

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Display weights 1 to 100 only case below code working good.
>   path:sites/all/modules/weight/weight.module file 751 line

```
/**
 * Get an array of options to for selecting a weight.
 */
function _weight_get_options($range) {
  $max = $range;

  $options = array();

  for ($i =1; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    $options[$i] = $i;
  }

  return $options;
}

Before code:

/**
 * Get an array of options to for selecting a weight.
 */
function _weight_get_options($range) {
  $max = $range;
  $min = $max * -1;
  $options = array();

  for ($i =0; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    $options[$i] = $i;
  }

  return $options;
```